# Computed Twig solution not showing in preview?

Tags: webforms

I'm trying to understand Twig.

This is what I have got

{{ (data.number_1) * (data.number_2) }}

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Why doesn't the preview page calculate the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. You need to create a "Preview Page" as per Computed Twig example.

webform 5.x has an inbuilt preview page which does not recalculate when viewed.

[image]

Comment: Computed Twig elements should be appearing the preview the page. This sound like a bug/issue.